# How can I fix scroll occurring twice when using this page transition on any browser on Mac?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, macos

I am experiencing an issue on my website that is using this page transition plugin whereby the transition occurs twice on Mac but works fine on other platforms. The transition occurs twice due to scroll event firing more than once.This behavior is only present on Mac regardless of browser.

Anyone have any ideas on how I can begin tackling this?

This is the link to the original page of the plugin:
https://github.com/HTML50/cubeTransition.js

Here is the demo page where the problem occurs:
https://html50.github.io/cubeTransition.js/

I have added a scroll delay on my website where I am using the plugin to try and fix it but it seems the second scroll occurs after the delay timer runs out. This seems to be an issue with scroll acceleration on Mac.

```
$(document).ready(

function () {
    var throttle = 1000;
    var time = -1;
    $(document).mousewheel(function (e, delta) {
        var now = Date.now();
        if (time !== -1 && now - time < throttle)
            return;

        time = now;
        e.preventDefault();
        if (delta < 0) {
            trans('down')
        } else {
            trans('up')
        }
    });
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 38 || e && e.keyCode == 37) {
            trans('up')
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 39 || e && e.keyCode == 40) {
            trans('down')
        }

    });

    $(document).swipe({
        swipe: function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
            if (direction == "up") {
                trans('down')
            } else if (direction == "down") {
                trans('up')
            }
        }
    });


    $('.navitems>li').on('click', function() {
        openIndex($(this).index() + 1);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some collaboration from the creator of the page transition plugin and various sources like stack overflow we have arrived at a solution.

There is a plugin someone wrote called wheel-indicator.js which allows detection of a track pad and presents various options to act appropriately. It works perfect on OSX across all browsers without breaking other platforms.

For more info on inertial scrolling present on OSX and touch pad devices please take a look at some demos on JS Fiddle:

1)http://jsfiddle.net/n7bk6pb9/1/ (Scroll Graphic Visualizer)

```
var canvas     = $('canvas'),
ctx        = canvas[0].getContext("2d"),
deltas     = [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
lastPeak   = 0,
center     = null,
x          = 0;

function resize() {
    ctx.canvas.width  = $(window).innerWidth();
    ctx.canvas.height = $(window).innerHeight();
    center = Math.floor(ctx.canvas.height / 2);
    clear();
    guides();
}

function clear() {
    x = 0;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
}

function guides() {
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
    ctx.fillRect(0, center, ctx.canvas.width, 1);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#0f0';
    ctx.fillRect(0, center - 60, ctx.canvas.width, 1);
    ctx.fillRect(0, center + 60, ctx.canvas.width, 1);
}

function hash() {
    ctx.fillStyle = '#00f';
    ctx.fillRect(x, center + 10, 1, -20);
}

function hasPeak() {
    if (deltas[0] == null) return false;

    var flat = [];
    for (var i in deltas) {
        flat.push(Math.abs(deltas[i]));
    }

    if (
        Math.abs(x - lastPeak) > 10      &&
        flat[0] <  flat[4] &&
        flat[1] <= flat[4] &&
        flat[2] <= flat[4] &&
        flat[3] <= flat[4] &&
        flat[5] <= flat[4] &&
        flat[6] <= flat[4] &&
        flat[7] <= flat[4] &&
        flat[8] <  flat[4]
    ) {
        lastPeak = x;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

resize();
guides();

$(window)
.on('resize', resize)
.on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
    var delta  = e.type == 'mousewheel' ? e.originalEvent.wheelDelta * -1 : 40 * e.originalEvent.detail;

    if (hasPeak()) hash();
    else if ((deltas[8] == null || Math.abs(deltas[8]) == 120) && Math.abs(delta) == 120) hash();

    ctx.fillStyle = '#f00';
    ctx.fillRect(x, center, 1, delta * -1);

    guides();

    deltas.shift();
    deltas.push(delta);
    x++
  if (x > ctx.canvas.width) clear();
});
```

2)http://jsfiddle.net/n7bk6pb9/7/ (Scroll Events Detection)

```
    // Globals:

var deltas = [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
    timer  = null,
    lock   = 0,
    seen   = 0;

// Search for an inertial peak (which represents a trackpade mouse wheel gesture):

function hasPeak() {

    // Decrement the lock.

    if (lock > 0) {
        lock--;
        return false;
    }

    // If the oldest delta is null, there can't be a peak yet; so return.

    if (deltas[0] == null) return false;

    // Otherwise, check for a peak signature where the middle delta (4)
    // is the highest among all other deltas to the left or right.

    if (
        deltas[0] <  deltas[4] &&
        deltas[1] <= deltas[4] &&
        deltas[2] <= deltas[4] &&
        deltas[3] <= deltas[4] &&
        deltas[5] <= deltas[4] &&
        deltas[6] <= deltas[4] &&
        deltas[7] <= deltas[4] &&
        deltas[8] <  deltas[4]
    ) return true;

    // If no peak is found, return false.

    return false;
}

// Handle mouse wheel events:

$(window).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {

    // Convert the delta into a usable number (pretty standard).

    var delta  = e.type == 'mousewheel' ? e.originalEvent.wheelDelta * -1 : 40 * e.originalEvent.detail;

    // Check for an inertial peak. And if found, lock the peak
    // checking for 10 more events (decremented in hasPeak on
    // each new event) to prevent the sample window from registering
    // true more than once for each peak.

    if (hasPeak()) {
        lock = 10;
        seen++;
        $('div').text('Inertial Gesture Found! (' + seen + ' total)');
    }

    // Otherwise, check for normal mouse wheel events by assuming
    // past and present deltas would be 120 exactly, and skip nulls.

    else if ((deltas[8] == null || deltas[8] == 120) && Math.abs(delta) == 120)
        $('div').text('Mouse Wheel Event Found!');

    // Shift the deltas backward and add the newest (maintaining the sample window).

    deltas.shift();
    deltas.push(Math.abs(delta));

    // Clear the notification (demonstration purposes, only).

    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        $('div').text('Waiting ...');
    }, 200);
});
```

Comment: Since I do not have enough reputation to post more than 2 links. Here is the link to the Github Issue page I mentioned above: [issue](https://github.com/HTML50/cubeTransition.js/issues/2) 
and the link to the wheel-indication plugin here: [wheel-indicator.js](https://github.com/Promo/wheel-indicator)